# Why isn't this printf statement executed

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
printf("Hello, to the Simulation world,\n");

int pid = fork();
if(pid < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Oops something went wrong\n");
}else if (pid == 0){
    printf("I'm child, and I do all the work, \n");
    printf("This isn't printed");
    // Any printf statement over here isn't executed \\

    execvp(argv[1], argv);
} else {
    wait(&pid);
    printf("I'm Parent and I do nothing, but I will wait till my child dies.\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Any printf statement below the else if printf statement isn't shown,

Compiler used: gcc version 6.3.1 20170306 (GCC)

OS: Linux based,

My assumption: stderr is replacing current line output with its own data, but whenever input is in its own line like, `printf("This Line is Printed\n")`, I can see the output. But if I write it in this way `printf("This Line isn't Printed")`.

or

Is it happening only for me? Or some rendering problem with OS.

Output for my above program:

[image: Output]

Comment: what happens if you switch the order of the `wait` and `printf` calls?

Comment: Consider I have placed a `printf("hello");`, just below `printf("I'm child, and I do all the work,\n");`, that hello isn't printed on my terminal.

Comment: Man!!! It's working.

Comment: For me, it's working,

Comment: I have edited the code and added a screen-shot of my output, please reconsider checking once,

Comment: All I can ask you to try resetting your terminal.
Execute `stty sane`, `tput rs1`, `reset`

Comment: So what you're asking, is why when you don't properly terminate your output, does it not display? You have to have a `\n` for it to be outputted. I expect that stdout is wiped when the child exits or exec's a new command

Comment: `printf("This isn't printed");` doesn't flush stdout, and neither does `execvp`.

Comment: answer given by romaric crailox have solved it, as per my understanding with given solution, something is printed  to stdout until `\n` is occured or program exits normally, over here since execvp replaces current process it is unable to write it.(I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `fflush(NULL);` before `execvp(argv[1], argv);`

From man fflush :

> For  output  streams,  fflush()  forces  a  write of all user-space
>   buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's
>   underlying write function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please elaborate, why is that statement in buffer state rather than printing each and every `printf `statement at once.

Comment: As you write on a comment, "This isn't printed" si not null terminated, so printf can not know if string is finish or not. So it does not print it, instead of you force it with a call to fflush function.